# No proper subset of $\mathbb C$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$-is my proof correct?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to prove that no proper subset of $\mathbb C$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$. This is my proof.

Suppose not. Let $A$ be a proper subset of $\mathbb C$ biholomorphic to it, say via the map $f$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, it carries open sets to open sets (Open Mapping Theorem) and since $\mathbb C$ is open in $\mathbb C$, $A$ must be open. But since $f$ is a biholomorphism, it's inverse is also a holomorphism and hence continuous. So preimage of a closed set under $f^{-1}$ is is closed in $\mathbb C$. So $f^{-1}$ carries closed sets of $\mathbb C$ to closed sets and since $\mathbb C$ is closed in $\mathbb C$, $A$ must also be closed. $A$ is non-empty clearly and $\mathbb C$ being connected and $A$ clopen $A$=$\mathbb C$ must hold.

Is this proof correct? I can't spot a mistake. A proof I saw of this involves much more machinery that what I've used. I seem to have got it too easily. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that $A = f^{-1}(\mathbb{C})$ is closed **in $A$**, which doesn't give you anything. Your argument then supposes that $A$ would be closed in $\mathbb{C}$.

Note that since you never used any property of holomorphic functions except continuity and openness, if it were correct, your proof would show that no proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is *homeomorphic* to $\mathbb{C}$, but every simply connected non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. disks, half-planes) is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.